# Closest distance of approach

Tags: forces, electrostatics, energy, energy-conservation, charge

Suppose a charged body $q_0$ is at rest. Another charged body $q_1$ at infinite distance starts moving towards $q_0$ with velocity $v_1$. Gradually the velocity of $q_1$ will decrease and that of $q_0$ will increase.(taking same sign of charges)

Now it is said that the closest possible distance between $q_0$ and $q_1$ is *when both of their velocities will be same*. But why is it the case? What does equal velocity have to do with minimum distance? Please enlighten me.

Comment: "It is said..." It is said by whom? Can you provide a reference so we can see some of the same context you seem to be familiar with? Also, are you considering collisions at *any* impact parameter? Or are you just considering head-on collisions where the particles are travelling directly along whatever force vector connects them? Seems like this "it is said" assertion can not possibly hold for large impact parameters...

Comment: Have you considered (a) finding the derivative of the distance between the particles, or (b) analyzing the problem in the center-of-momentum reference frame? In neither case do you need to care about the details of the electromagnetic repulsion, except that each velocity goes monotonically from its initial to its final value.

Comment: Like hft I’ve never heard it said. Where did you hear it?

Comment: Yeah, this is looking an awful lot like a homework problem. One way to approach this is the rewrite the total energy in terms of the center-of-mass kinetic energy (which is constant since the CM velocity is constant) and the relative kinetic energy. The potential energy term already explicitly depends only on the relative position. In addition to the center-of-mass, it will also be helpful for OP to recall the definition of the reduced mass $\mu = \frac{m_1 m_0}{(m_1 + m_0)}$.

Comment: And I think OP's assertion really only applies to the head-on-collision case, since in other cases you can't be assured that the velocities will ever actually be equal. But in the head-on repulsive case you can. And then, after re-writing the energy in terms of the relative kinetic energy (dependence of KE on relative velocity) it is almost trivial to prove what OP is asking about.

Answer (score 1):

Identical velocities implies zero *relative* velocity, meaning the objects are not moving with respect to each other - they are not getting any closer or farther from one another. Since the objects were originally getting closer to one another, achieving zero relative velocity means the objects have stopped getting closer - they are as close as they are going to get.

Answer (score 0):

Say the two objects are moving to the right. As long as the one on the left is moving faster it gaining on the other and the the distance between them is decreasing. Once the one on the right is moving faster the distance between them will be increasing. The transition between when the distance is decreasing and when it is increasing occurs when the speeds are the same and represents the minimum separation.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the total energy as:
$$
H = C + \frac{1}{2}\mu v^2 + \frac{kq_1q_0}{r}\;, \qquad(1)
$$
where $r$ is the relative distance, $v$ is the relative velocity, $\mu$ is the reduced mass, and $C$ is a constant (which you will be able to explicitly determine, but which does not matter since it is constant).

Now look at Eq. (1) and ask yourself: What is the smallest that the $\frac{1}{2}\mu v^2$ term can be? And when does that occur?